# A Fortran module needs a subroutine located in another module

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I have a problem like this:

1. main.f90 --> contains MAIN file
2. sub_A.f90 --> contains subroutine A
3. sub_B.f90 --> contains subroutine B
4. other_stuffs.f90 --> contains all functions required by points 2 and 3.

All four points are written separately.

**main.f90**

```
include sub_A.f90
include sub_B.f90
include other_stuffs.f90

program MAIN
use A
use B
use other
     ...
     call proc_A   
     call_proc_B
end program MAIN
```

**sub_A.f90**

```
module A
contains
    subroutine proc_A
    use other            
    ...
        call compute_something_1
    end subroutine proc_A
end module A
```

**sub_B.f90**

```
module B
contains  
    subroutine proc_B
    use other            
    ...
        call compute_something_2
    end subroutine proc_B
end module B
```

**other_stuffs.f90**

```
module other
contains  
    subroutine compute_something_1
    ...
    end subroutine compute_something_1

    subroutine compute_something_2
    ...
    end subroutine compute_something_2
end module other
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: subroutines and functions in modules must be preceded by line `contains`.

Comment: You really have to say something more specific than "didn't work". What happened? I can see at least one issue in the code you've provided (you need to put subroutines in a `contains` section of the module, e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/1139/usage-of-modules/3671/module-syntax#t=201707100901444104929)). What do you mean by "my assumption didn't work"?

Comment: @d_1999: The executable file was not created.

Comment: @M.Chinoune: Thanks

Comment: 'The executable file was not created' is not helpful. What error message did you get? What compilation command, and what compiler version were you using?

Comment: the wrong think in your code is to include `sub_A.f90` and `sub_B.f90` before its dependency `other_stuffs.f90` .

Comment: The error messages are really necessary. That is probably the reason for those downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `contains` section in the module `other`.
Only subroutines, functions and variables that are located in the `contains` section are accessible from outside the module.

```
module other

contains  
    subroutine compute_something_1
    ...
    end subroutine compute_something_1

    subroutine compute_something_2
    ...
    end subroutine compute_something_2
end module other
```

Comment: Thanks @KaeptnNemo. I didn't forget putting `contains` in my real code; I forgot to write it in the above code instead. The answer is that I should put the `use` statement prior to  entering the subroutine. I've edited my post and I'll write the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be as follow

**main.f90**

```
include other_stuffs.f90     !It becomes the first now
include sub_A.f90
include sub_B.f90

program MAIN
use other
use A
use B
     ...
     call proc_A   
     call_proc_B
end program MAIN
```

**sub_A.f90**

```
module A
use other     ! CORRECT PLACE
contains
    subroutine proc_A
    ! use other             !WRONG PLACE !!!
    ...
        call compute_something_1
    end subroutine proc_A
end module A
```

**sub_B.f90**

```
module B
use other     ! CORRECT PLACE
contains  
    subroutine proc_B
    ! use other             !WRONG PLACE !!!
    ...
        call compute_something_2
    end subroutine proc_B
end module B
```

**other_stuffs.f90**

```
module other
contains  
    subroutine compute_something_1
    ...
    end subroutine compute_something_1

    subroutine compute_something_2
    ...
    end subroutine compute_something_2
end module other
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having the `use` statements in the subroutines of the modules (unless things are needed in the module itself).